# Visual Studio 2022 - Not re-loading externally referenced DLLs when re-built

Tags: visual-studio

I have a core domain solution that I compile into a set of DLLs, which I then reference(By browsing, not by project reference) in my primary solutions projects.  In Visual Studio 2017 when I recompiled the DLLs in my external solution the changes were picked up within a few seconds and I could reference the new code straight away.  In VS 2022 the changes are never picked up and I have to re-laod the solution in some way to make them get picked up, either by exiting completely, or closing and re-opening the solution.
Is there a setting that will fix this, or is there an error occuring with my particular setup?

I have tried searching the options menu as much as possible, and the obvious google/stack searches, but with no success.  I've even tried deleting the DLLs completely before recompiling, but no joy.